# Managing Orphaned .avhdx Files in Hyper-V with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, virtualization, hyper-v, disk-space-utilization, windows-command-prompt

I'm managing a Hyper-V environment and looking to clean up my hard drive to free up space. Specifically, I want to delete orphaned `.avhdx` files and possibly move some to external storage. I prefer using cmd/batch and/or PowerShell for this task.

So far, I've tried using PowerShell to correlate `.avhdx` files with the list of VMs and checkpoints in the Hyper-V Manager GUI. However, I'm facing challenges in accurately identifying which `.avhdx` files are orphaned and can be safely deleted or moved.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using `Get-VM` and `Get-VHD` cmdlets to list VHDX files associated with VMs.
2. Matching these files against all `.vhdx` and `.avhdx` files on the disk using `Get-ChildItem`.

Despite these efforts, I'm not confident in the accuracy of the results, especially in determining the linkage between `.avhdx` files and specific VMs or checkpoints.

I'm seeking advice on:

- Effective methods to identify orphaned `.avhdx` files using PowerShell or cmd.
- Best practices for managing these files in a Hyper-V environment.
- Any scripts or tools that can facilitate this process.

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

**P.S.** I have also posted the question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperV/comments/18wpyby/best_practices_for_managing_orphaned_avhdx_files/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on r/HyperV subreddit.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a PowerShell solution. This script will help identify which `.avhdx` files in the Hyper-V environment are orphaned, meaning any VM snapshots are not currently used. Here's how it works:

```perl
# Get the list of AVHDX files used by the VM snapshots
$snapshotVHDs = Get-VM | Get-VMSnapshot | ForEach-Object {
    $snapshotName = $_.Name
    $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HardDrives | ForEach-Object {
        Get-VHD $_.Path | Where-Object { $_.Path -like "*.avhdx" } | Select-Object -Property Path
    }
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -Unique

# Get all AVHDX files in the specified directory
$allVHDs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks" -Filter *.avhdx -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

# Compare the lists to find orphaned AVHDX files
$orphanedVHDs = $allVHDs | Where-Object { $_ -notin $snapshotVHDs }

# Output the orphaned files
$orphanedVHDs | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Orphaned File: $_" }
```

**How it Works:**

1. **Snapshot VHDs Collection**: The script first collects the paths of all `.avhdx` files that are currently in use by VM snapshots.
2. **Directory Scan for AVHDX Files**: It then scans the specified directory (`C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks`) for all `.avhdx` files.
3. **Identifying Orphaned Files**: By comparing these two sets of files, the script determines which `.avhdx` files in the directory are not currently used by any snapshots. These are your orphaned files.
4. **Results**: Finally, it outputs the paths of these orphaned `.avhdx` files.

This script should help safely identify orphaned `.avhdx` files that can then be considered deleted or archived, depending on the cleanup strategy. However, as a precaution, always ensure that these files are indeed not required by any VMs before proceeding with deletion to avoid any accidental data loss.